# FFJORD: Free-form Continuous Dynamics for Scalable Reversible Generative Models

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to understand this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.01367) and the [github](https://github.com/rtqichen/ffjord) code given with it, specifically the **CNF script**: in the loss function (**compute_bits_per_dim**) the **Normalizing Flow** is run forward to retrieve the base point **z**:

`z, delta_logp = model(x, zero)`

However, in the paper it is stated that the Normalizing flow must run *backwards*, taking the observed point **x** as input and running from **t1** to **t0** in order to retrieve the base point **z**. Does anyone have an explanation

Comment: From your reference for equation (6): *This approach is a continuous-time analog to the backpropgation algorithm (Rumelhart et al., 1986; Andersson, 2013) and can be combined with gradient-based optimization methods to fit the parameters θ.*

Comment: Not equation (6) but equation (4). z0 is obtained by integrating backwards (pay attention to the integral bounds they are reversed t1 to t0). But the code and the Algorithm 1 seem to miss this